# Rails + Rolify Gem: Assigning an :admin role to ALL users in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rolify

I am using the Rolify gem (https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) to assign roles to users of my web app.

I understand from the documentation that I can do this to assign a role to an individual user record:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role :admin
```

Which is fine, and what I'm doing with new accounts that are being created. However, how can I assign the `:admin` role to ALL users within my users table en masse?

I tried playing around with this in my rails console but didn't have any luck.

Comment: do you want to assign admin role to all your user that are currently in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `users`

```
#= select * from users;
 id |   name   |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | Kristján | 2015-06-05 04:47:58.037205 | 2015-06-05 04:47:58.037205
```

and `roles`

```
#= select * from roles;
 id | name  | resource_id | resource_type |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+-------+-------------+---------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | admin |           ∅ | ∅             | 2015-06-05 04:50:27.015613 | 2015-06-05 04:50:27.015613
```

and your join table is `users_roles`

```
#= \d users_roles
  Table "public.users_roles"
 Column  |  Type   | Modifiers
---------+---------+-----------
 user_id | integer |
 role_id | integer |
```

You can insert an `admin` role for each user with

```
#= insert into users_roles select id, 1 from users;
```

Or if you prefer to do it from your Rails console (and have patience, if there are a lot of records):

```
User.find_each { |user| user.add_role :admin }
```

Comment: Hi Kristjan, so this works for me! I have a question though...say I have a users and customers table. I want to then apply a role to users whose email also exists in customers table. How would I do that?

Comment: Simple way is to add a condition to the query: `where users.email in (select email from customers)`. Or in Ruby `user.add_role :admin if Customer.exists?(email: user.email)`.